# How to i solve this Exponential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

How to solve this exponential equation?

$$7 \cdot 3^{x+1} - 5^{x+2}= 3^{x+4}- 5^{x+3}$$

Comment: Good first step is to write everything using only $x$ in the exponents.  $7\cdot 3^{x+1}$ for example can be rewritten as $7\cdot 3\cdot 3^x$ and $5^{x+2}$ can be rewritten as $5\cdot 5\cdot 5^x$.  Then try to simplify.  Logarithms will likely come into play as well near the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group them according to the base:

\begin{align}
&7\cdot 3^{x+1}-3^{x+4}=5^{x+2}-5^{x+3}\\
\implies&3^{x+1}(7-3^3)=5^{x+2}(1-5)\\
\implies&3^{x+1}\cdot (-20)=5^{x+2}\cdot(-4)\\
\implies&3^{x+1}\cdot 5=5^{x+2}\\
\implies&3^{x+1}=5^{x+1}
\end{align}

Generally, you would now use logarithms, although this case is rather obvious.

Answer (score 2):

$$\\ 7 \cdot 3^{x+1} - 5^{x+2}= 3^{x+4}- 5^{x+3}\\ 125\cdot { 5 }^{ x }-25\cdot { 5 }^{ x }=81\cdot { 3 }^{ x }-21\cdot { 3 }^{ x }\\ 100\cdot { 5 }^{ x }=60\cdot { 3 }^{ x }\\ { \left( \frac { 5 }{ 3 }  \right)  }^{ x }=\frac { 3 }{ 5 } \\ x=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$7 \cdot 3^{x+1} - 5^{x+2}= 3^{x+4}- 5^{x+3}$$
$$21 \cdot 3^{x} -25\cdot 5^{x}= 81\cdot3^{x}- 125\cdot5^{x}$$
$$100\cdot 5^{x}= 60\cdot3^{x}$$
$$\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^x=\frac{3}{5}=\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{-1}$$
$$x=-1$$